# How can trigger to datatable's search filter with multi select box values?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can we use seacrh filter properties datatable from multi select box values?

Here select box(multiselect);

```
<select id="dbox" multiple="true">
<option value="test1">Test1</option>
<option value="test2">Test2</option>
<option value="test3">Test3</option>
</select>
```

When dbox selecttion changed trigger works on datatable search filter:

I  tried this jquery code:

```
$("select#dbox").on("change",function(){

 var val=$(this).val();
oTable.fnFilter(val);

});
```

But it doesnt work.

How can we do this?

Thanks

Comment: you can try my yadcf plugin for datatables, see the filter in the first column header http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reference code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6uQ2/26/)

HTML:

```
<h4>Select your multiple filter</h4>
<div>
    <select id="dbox" name="categories" multiple>
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="Home">Home</option>
        <option value="Work">Work</option>
        <option value="City">City</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>Table of items</h4>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>Lamp</td><td>Home</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Desk</td><td>Work</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td>Books</td><td>Home</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Cars</td><td>City</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Desk</td><td>Work</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Photocopying</td><td>Work</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Clip</td><td>Work</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Street</td><td>City</td></tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var dataTable = $('table').dataTable();
$("select#dbox").change( function () {
    var choosedFilter = $('#dbox').val();
    var choosedString = choosedFilter.join("|");
    dataTable.fnFilter(choosedString,2,true,false);
});
```

Comment: I am using datatable version 1.10.4 , so it doesnt filter to 2 or more filter values

Answer (score 3):

Try to use search function.

```
$("#dbox").on("change",function(){
    var val=$(this).val();
    oTable.search(val).draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#myInputTextbox').keyup(function(e) {
      $('#myDataTable').dataTable().fnFilter(this.value);
    });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.